# Tuple with missing value

Tags: python, tuples

I have a function in python that does error checking on a string.  If the function finds an error it will return a tuple with an error code and an identifier for that error.  Later in the program I have the function that handles the error.  It accepts the tuple into two variables.

```
errCode, i = check_string(s,pathType)
```

check_string is the function that produces the tuple.  What I want it to does is return just zero if there is no error.  When a zero is returned the above code seems to fail because there is nothing for the variable i.

Is there an easy way to get this to work or do I just need to have the program return a tuple of 0 and 0 if no error is found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the exception system for this.

```
class StringError(Exception):
    NO_E = 0
    HAS_Z = 1

def string_checker(string):
    if 'e' not in string:
        raise StringError('e not found in string', StringError.NO_E)
    if 'z' in string:
        raise StringError('z not allowed in string', StringError.HAS_Z)
    return string.upper()

s = 'testing'
try:
    ret = string_checker(s)
    print 'String was okay:', ret
except StringError as e:
    print 'String not okay with an error code of', e.args[1]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting the problem, but all this to simply check if the tuple contains one or two values? *Not* meant as a criticism, and clearly using the exception mechanism has its place (given EAFP), but seems more complex than necessary.

Comment: @Levon Returning error values is rather C-ish and not very Pythonic. Maybe I've read too much in-between the lines, but given the OP's first paragraph, my first thought was "use Exceptions" - in this case, `string_checker` returns a valid string (without using tuples and codes), otherwise raises, which can be handled where ever required... Just seems a "cleaner" design to me.

Comment: @Levon You're welcome. It's also easy to "forget" to check error codes leading to something breaking later, or even worse, being a silent bug that does "who knows what" over time...

Comment: Yes, that's a very valid point, and a definite advantage of exceptions, they won't let you forget them for sure :) and require to be handled. I guess it's a matter of when and where to use them, but I understand your reasons for this solution much better now.

Comment: Great. This is pretty much what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply check the length of the tuple before trying to retrieve the values?

```
err_tup = check_String(s, pathType)
if len(err_tup) == 2:
    errCode, i = err_tup
else: # assuming it can only be 1 otherwise
    errCode = err_tup
```

This would work without making any changes to the rest of your code that generates the tuple, and is semantically clear.

Based on *"Simple is better than complex."*

Answer (score 1):

You could use None as the value for error

```
def check_string(s,pathType):
    # No error
    return (None, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to return zero:

```
foo = func()
if not foo:
    print 'No errors'
else:
    # foo is tuple
```