# python tuple with missing entry

Tags: python, parsing, bibtex

I am trying to parse a `bibtex` file with `python3`'s `bibtexparser` module.

A sample bibtex file is:

```
@article{ebert2013,
  Title={First-principles calculation of the Gilbert damping parameter via the linear response formalism with application to magnetic transition metals and alloys},
  Author={Mankovsky, S. and K{\"o}dderitzsch, D. and Woltersdorf, G and Ebert, H.},
  Volume={87},
  Pages={1},
  Year={2013},
  Journal={Phys. Rev. B}
}
@article{ebert2011,
  title = {\textit{Ab Initio} Calculation of the Gilbert Damping Parameter via the Linear Response Formalism},
  author = {Ebert, H. and Mankovsky, S. and K{\"o}dderitzsch, D. and Kelly, P. J.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {107},
  pages = {066603},
  month = {Aug},
  publisher = {American Physical Society}
}
@article{paudyal2013,
  author={Narayan Poudyal and J Ping Liu},
  title={Advances in nanostructured permanent magnets research},
  journal={Journal of Physics D: Applied Physics},
  volume={46},
  number={4},
  pages={043001},
  year={2013}
}
```

**Note** See the 2nd item does not have any `year` key.

Now, I am trying to parse this file as:

```
    import bibtexparser
    from bibtexparser.bparser import BibTexParser
    # from bibtexparser.bwriter import BibTexWriter
    from bibtexparser.bibdatabase import BibDatabase

    db = BibDatabase()
    with open('report.bib') as bibtex_file:
        parser = BibTexParser()
        db = bibtexparser.load(bibtex_file, parser=parser)
        for i in range(0, len(db.entries)):
            try:
                tuples = (db.entries[i]["title"],db.entries[i]["author"],
                         db.entries[i]["journal"],db.entries[i]["year"])
            except(KeyError):
                continue
            print(tuples)
```

Since, it does not find the `year` entry, it is skipping the 2nd element all together; giving output as:

```
('First-principles calculation of the Gilbert damping parameter via the linear\nresponse formalism with application to magnetic transition metals and alloys', 'Mankovsky, S. and K{\\"o}dderitzsch, D. and Woltersdorf, G and Ebert, H.', 'Phys. Rev. B', '2013')
('Advances in nanostructured permanent magnets research', 'Narayan Poudyal and J Ping Liu', 'Journal of Physics D: Applied Physics', '2013')
```

But, the desired behaviour is to get the entry with a `NULL` value for the missing item.

How I can do that?

I have actually gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708568/tuple-with-missing-value) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747224/append-to-a-list-defined-in-a-tuple-is-it-a-bug) se question among others, but have not gained much.

Kindly help.

Comment: can't you also just iterate on db.entries instead of using for i in range + len.... ? if yes it would be way cleaner ;-) for entry in db.entries: ...entry.get('title'), entry.get('author'), entry.get('journal'), entry.get('year')

Answer (score 3):

use `.get`, and you can remove your `try/except` for **KeyError** as well

```
db.entries[i].get("year")
```

With dictionaries, it is often recommended to use `dict.get(<key>, default=None)`, to prevent **KeyError** exceptions, while iterating on **non-sanitized** data.

Also have a look to `dict.pop(<key>, default)` which also prevents exceptions but forces you to provide a default value.